# File not found "Form2.dcu"

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I can't resolve this problem, anyone can help?

Unit 1 code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Form2; //error here

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
```

and here is Unit 2

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    CESTITAMO: TLabel;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Rezultat11: TLabel;
    REZULTAT21: TLabel;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

yes I created Form2 made it's caption "Cestitke!" and kept name as Form2

And I would like to know how to fix it in future, thanks

Comment: You really should accept one of those answers. Not accepting discourages people from helping you in the future and possibly others as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the error.

Your Uses is

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Form2; //error here
```

but to access Form2, what you need to include in this list is **not** the name of the form, but instead the name of the unit in which it is declared, i.e. `Unit2`.

So, your Uses list should read:

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Unit2;
```

But usually in a situation like this, it is sufficient to include `Unit2` in a `Uses` list in the implementation section of Unit1.

Answer (score 3):

There is no unit Form2.pas. Replace Form2 with Unit2 in your uses clause.

Answer (score 2):

Delete ", Form2" from uses and add "uses Unit2;" to the implementation section. This is a working example:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

{uses //Delphi 10.2
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;}

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;


type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses Unit2;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.ShowModal; //or Form2.Show;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, janeks3! Code-only answers are discouraged here, as they provide no insight into how the problem is solved. Please update your answer with an explanation of how your code works so that future visitors to this site can understand your solution :)